# What does this saying mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning

I encounter an incomprehensible saying:

> Except as a man handled an axe*, he had no way of knowing a fool.

while reading [this tutorial](https://math.dartmouth.edu/~doyle/docs/whyme/whyme/whyme.html).

---

*I wanted to add a mark here which means the possible error derives from the source

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a quote from Spenser:

> "Men of the wood and lumberjacks,
>   they judged me by the appropriate tool.
>   Except as a fellow handled an axe
>   they had no way of knowing a fool."

I take it to mean that people can judge you only in terms of things that they understand.

Comment: The quote is from Robert Frost's [*Two Tramps in Mud Time*](https://owlcation.com/humanities/Robert-Frosts-Two-Tramps-in-Mud-Time).

Answer (score 1):

The speaker is saying that lumberjacks had no way to judge a man's importance or value or capabilities except by observing how he handled an axe.

Comment: Surely, the man handling the axe is observing the speaker of the saying, who isn't necessarily holding an axe.